# MapStruct - MapperImpl not found

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am using Mapstruct in a plain Java project that is an OSGi bundle. I have added some basic code:

```
package com.XXX.XXX.test;

import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

import java.util.Map;

@Mapper
public interface AccountPreferencesMapper {
    AccountPreferencesMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(AccountPreferencesMapper.class);

    @Mapping(expression = "java((String) r.get(\"defaultName\"))", target = "name")
    MappedAccountPreferences toMappedAccountPreferences(Map<String, Object> r);
}
```

And

```
package com.XXX.XXX.test;

public class MappedAccountPreferences {
    public String name;
}
```

When I am building the package it will generate the Implementation within:

> target/generated-sources/annotations/AccountPreferencesMapperImpl.java

The issue is that, when I am calling AccountPreferencesMapper.MAPPER I am unable to get it. It will say that it is **null** or I am getting: **Could not initialize class com.XXX.XXX.test.AccountPreferencesMapper**

I am in the same package with the following code:

```
Map accountPreferencesMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
accountPreferencesMap.put("defaultName", "User Name");
MappedAccountPreferences dto = AccountPreferencesMapper.MAPPER.toMappedAccountPreferences( accountPreferencesMap );
```

Please note that I have to compile the code using: **mvn clean install** and **mvn content-package:install** (I am not using any editor for the build)

I have tried adding in POM the mapstruct-jdk8 / mapstruct-processor as separate dependency as explained in other stackoverflow mapstruct similar issues but it doesn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: Have your tried `@Mapping(target= "r.defaultName", source= "name")
    MappedAccountPreferences toMappedAccountPreferences(Map<String, Object> r);` ?

Comment: I have tried with r.defaultName instead of expression. The problem seems to be on the referencing part. The project is not able to see the Impl class from target/generated-source/annotations/

Comment: I miss the package in so: `target/generated-sources/annotations/com/XXX/XXX/test/AccountPreferencesMapperImpl.java`

Comment: And.. you could define a `default` method just mapping method in stead of using an expression. Like `default String mapFromDefaultName(Map in) { return in.get("defaultName") }` which will be automatically called by `toMappedAccountPreferences`

Answer (score 0):

in the AccountPreferencesMapper  interface you don't need to use MAPPER

```
@Mapper
public interface AccountPreferencesMapper {

    @Mapping(expression = "java((String) r.get(\"defaultName\"))", target = "name")
    MappedAccountPreferences toMappedAccountPreferences(Map<String, Object> r);
}
```

after , in your service you can use the mapper like this :

```
        Map accountPreferencesMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        accountPreferencesMap.put("defaultName", "User Name");
        MappedAccountPreferences mappedAccountPreferences = accountPreferencesMapper.toMappedAccountPreferences(accountPreferencesMap);
```

- if you are using spring boot , in the class test you neesd to add :

  ```
    @SpringBootTest(classes = {AccountPreferencesMapperImpl.class})
    public class TestClass{

    }
  ```